# Using jquery equal height but need equal elements inside columns as well

Tags: jquery, html

I'm using a jQuery equal heights plugin for my columns but the designer wants from the price down to the add to cart button equalized as well. Is this possible to do with jQuery? I've tried adding it to the existing equal heights but actually I'm not that sure what I'm doing.

Here is the jquery:

```
 (function($) {
$.fn.equalHeights = function(minHeight, maxHeight) {
    tallest = (minHeight) ? minHeight : 0;
    this.each(function() {
        if($(this).height() > tallest) {
            tallest = $(this).height();
        }
    });
    if((maxHeight) && tallest > maxHeight) tallest = maxHeight;
    return this.each(function() {
        $(this).height(tallest).css("overflow","hidden");
    });
}
    })(jQuery);
```

This is the way one of the boxes is laid out:

```
<ul id="phones" class="clearfix">
<li class="phone">
<div class="top"></div>
<img src="/_img/2012/accessories_product.jpg" alt="phone" width="192" height="120"/>
<h2>BLACKBERRY MICRO-USB VEHICLE POWER ADAPTER</h2>
<p>Product description sed ut perspici atis unde omnis iste natus sit volupt.</p>
<div class="btm">   
<h3 class="price">$29.99</h3>
<p class="modelnumb">MODEL #: 1234567890</p>
<a href="#" class="btn btn_addtocart">Add To Cart</a>
</div>
</li>
```

I'm calling it on the page like this:

```
<script>
$j(document).ready(function() {
$j("#phones > li.phone").equalHeights(412);
});
</script>
```

I've included an image of what it's looking like now:

[image]

If anyone could give me some help I would appreciate it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please post a demo over at [JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) that we can work with.

Comment: Okay, I tried to recreate it in an ugly way over at JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/guEcu/  I've tried to absolutely position from the price down to the add to cart btn but of course that screws it up if someone adds extra text into the box. Thanks

Comment: The submitted jsfiddle code looks fine to me in google chrome (mac)? And I'm not entirely sure why you don't just give each div and the `<p>` tags a fixed height?

Answer (score 0):

So, I now found a solution to my problem so I'll answer my own question. Basically I had a bunch of boxes that all needed to be the same height. At the bottom of each box was a price, model # and button. Above this was text that of course had variable heights and so from the price on down there were variable heights box to box.

I was using a jQuery plugin for equal boxes so instead of applying it to the entire box, I applied it to a div that took care of just the top part of the box including the text and stopped at the price. This solved the problem.

Maybe this can help someone else out with the same problem. Thanks for your suggestions.